# Issue when install iOS app on Visual Studio 2015 throw Xamarin Mac Agent

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, mono

I am having an issue in Visual Studio 2015 when try to debug my app throw Xamarin Mac Agent(MacInCloud).

This is the log from output in VS2015:

> Launch failed. The app 'TodoREST.iOS' could not be launched on 'iPhone
>   5s iOS 10.1'. Error: An error occured on client IDB420719 while
>   executing a reply for topic xvs/idb/4.2.0.719/launch-app.

Also this is the log who Xamarin provides via VS:

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.IOS.IdbClient Error: 0 : [2016-11-07
>   20:41:48.4612] Launch failed. The app 'TodoREST.iOS' could not be
>   launched on 'iPhone 5s iOS 10.1'. Error: An error occured on client
>   IDB420719 while executing a reply for topic
>   xvs/idb/4.2.0.719/launch-app. Please check the logs for more details.
>   System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: StartIndex cannot be less than
>   zero. Parameter name: startIndex at System.String.Substring
>   (System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x0009c] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs:1266
>   at System.String.Substring (System.Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.6.0-c8sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.6.0-branch-c8sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/string.cs:1232
>   at Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch.GetMTouchError (System.String message)
>   [0x0003c] in :0  at
>   Xamarin.Messaging.IDB.MTouch+d__8.MoveNext () [0x00233] in
>   :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

[image of vs after crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pLdY.png)

One more detail: Immediately after the app opens in simulator it automatically close.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=45214

Comment: @SushiHangover it doesnt work, but thanks anyway

Comment: Did you check the build log on the Mac to see if the root cause of the error is in there....

Comment: I have the same issue. It works fine with the simulator but the app closes immediatly on device.

Comment: @Daniel  let me know if you get the solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've just had this error too. From past experience, deployment issues with iOS often relate to Xamarin versions being out of sync between Visual Studio/Windows and your Mac build host.

Make sure you have installed the latest updates from the **stable** channel on both your Windows machine and your Mac.

In Visual Studio, select Tools > Options > Xamarin > Other and Select **Check now**

In Xamarin Studio on the Mac, select **Xamarin Studio Community** from the menu bar, and **Check for Updates...**

I had some updates pending and this worked for me.

Comment: This help to much nbut its not the solution thank you anyway @Tonic